# I want to put width and height directly in the style tag using quill-image-resize-module in vue2-editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, editor, nuxt.js

I implemented resize in image using quill-image-resize-module in vue2-editor, but now the width attribute is added to img and I want to copy it to the style attribute.

In the implementation of what I made, the img tag is css with width: calc (100% + 32px);

Because there is a translation and this cannot be corrected, I would like to be able to display something smaller or larger than the specified one by putting the size in the image with style.

It is like this in the current situation.

```
<img alt src="https://**********" width="100px">
```

I want to change it like this.

```
<img alt src="https://**********" style="width:100px">
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly the purpose behind this change so the community is able to assist

Comment: I wrote why this implementation is necessary this time.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the style tag to your css:

```
.img {
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

or if you use other img tags which should not be adjusted:

Your css:

```
#yourChoosenId {
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

Your html:

```
<img alt src="https://**********" id="yourChoosenId">
```